# Can I make external GraphQL API server for Next.JS app?

Tags: api, graphql, next.js, backend, vercel

I've just one question, can I make separate server app (backend) with GraphQL API for my Next.JS app (frontend)? I clearly understand technical part of such implementation, but what about supporting Next.JS advantages (for example ability of deploying on Vercel)?

In my opinion, this approach will support all things which available for normal Next.JS app with API Routes (api/graphql), I just make my own API (like very very small GraphCMS), but may be I missed something.

Thanks in advance for all your opinions!

Comment: Not entirely sure I understood your question fully, but you can create an external API if you want to. You don't _have_ to use Next.js API routes.

Comment: The main point of the question is whether using external GraphQL API can influence on Next.JS basic advantages. I've read some docs and realized that it should not influence.